# Calculating working days including holidays between dates without a calendar table in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay, so I've done quite a lot of reading on the possibility of emulating the networkdays function of excel in sql, and have come to the conclusion that by far the easiest solution is to have a calendar table which will flag working days or non working days.  However, due to circumstances out of my control, we don't have access to such a luxury and it's unlikely that we will any time in the near future.

Currently I have managed to bodge together what is undoubtedly a horrible ineffecient query in SQL that does work - the catch is, it will only work for a single client record at a time.

```
SELECT O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID,
       O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE,
       O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE,
      sum(CASE 
              When TO_CHAR(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE + rownum -1,'Day')
                   = 'Sunday   ' THEN 0
              When TO_CHAR(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE + rownum -1,'Day')
                   = 'Saturday ' THEN 0
              WHEN O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE + rownum - 1
                   IN ('03-01-2000','21-04-2000','24-04-2000','01-05-2000','29-05-2000','28-08-2000','25-12-2000','26-12-2000','01-01-2001','13-04-2001','16-04-2001','07-05-2001','28-05-2001','27-08-2001','25-12-2001','26-12-2001','01-01-2002','29-03-2002','01-04-2002','06-04-2002','03-06-2002','04-06-2002','26-08-2002','25-12-2002','26-12-2002','01-01-2003','18-04-2003','21-04-2003','05-05-2003','26-05-2003','25-08-2003','25-12-2003','26-12-2003','01-01-2004','09-04-2004','12-04-2004','03-05-2004','31-05-2004','30-08-2004','25-12-2004','26-12-2004','27-12-2004','28-12-2004','01-01-2005','03-01-2005','25-03-2005','28-03-2005','02-05-2005','30-05-2005','29-08-2005','27-12-2005','28-12-2005','02-01-2006','14-04-2006','17-04-2006','01-05-2006','29-05-2006','28-08-2006','25-12-2006','26-12-2006','02-01-2007','06-04-2007','09-04-2007','07-05-2007','28-05-2007','27-08-2007','25-12-2007','26-12-2007','01-01-2008','21-03-2008','24-03-2008','05-05-2008','26-05-2008','25-08-2008','25-12-2008','26-12-2008','01-01-2009','10-04-2009','13-04-2009','04-05-2009','25-05-2009','31-08-2009','25-12-2009','28-12-2009','01-01-2010','02-04-2010','05-04-2010','03-05-2010','31-05-2010','30-08-2010','24-12-2010','27-12-2010','28-12-2010','31-12-2010','03-01-2011','22-04-2011','25-04-2011','29-04-2011','02-05-2011','30-05-2011','29-08-2011','26-12-2011','27-12-2011') 
                   THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 
          END)-1 AS Week_Day
From O_ASSESSMENTS,
     ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('TYPE1')
  AND O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE >= '01/01/2012'
  AND O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID = 'A00000'
  AND ROWNUM <= O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE-O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE+1
GROUP BY
      O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID,
      O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE,
      O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE
```

Basically, I'm wondering if a) I should stop wasting my time on this or b) is it possible to get this to work for multiple clients?  Any pointers appreciated thanks!

Edit:  Further clarification - I already work out timescales using excel, but it would be ideal if we could do it in the report as the report in question is something that we would like end users to be able to run without any further manipulation.

Edit:

MarkBannister's answer works perfectly albeit slowly (though I had expected as much given it's not the preferred solution) - the challenge now lies in me integrating this into an existing report!

```
with
calendar_cte as (select
to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1 calendar_date,
case when to_char(to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1, 'day') in ('sunday   ','saturday ') then 0 when to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1 in ('03-01-2000','21-04-2000','24-04-2000','01-05-2000','29-05-2000','28-08-2000','25-12-2000','26-12-2000','01-01-2001','13-04-2001','16-04-2001','07-05-2001','28-05-2001','27-08-2001','25-12-2001','26-12-2001','01-01-2002','29-03-2002','01-04-2002','06-04-2002','03-06-2002','04-06-2002','26-08-2002','25-12-2002','26-12-2002','01-01-2003','18-04-2003','21-04-2003','05-05-2003','26-05-2003','25-08-2003','25-12-2003','26-12-2003','01-01-2004','09-04-2004','12-04-2004','03-05-2004','31-05-2004','30-08-2004','25-12-2004','26-12-2004','27-12-2004','28-12-2004','01-01-2005','03-01-2005','25-03-2005','28-03-2005','02-05-2005','30-05-2005','29-08-2005','27-12-2005','28-12-2005','02-01-2006','14-04-2006','17-04-2006','01-05-2006','29-05-2006','28-08-2006','25-12-2006','26-12-2006','02-01-2007','06-04-2007','09-04-2007','07-05-2007','28-05-2007','27-08-2007','25-12-2007','26-12-2007','01-01-2008','21-03-2008','24-03-2008','05-05-2008','26-05-2008','25-08-2008','25-12-2008','26-12-2008','01-01-2009','10-04-2009','13-04-2009','04-05-2009','25-05-2009','31-08-2009','25-12-2009','28-12-2009','01-01-2010','02-04-2010','05-04-2010','03-05-2010','31-05-2010','30-08-2010','24-12-2010','27-12-2010','28-12-2010','31-12-2010','03-01-2011','22-04-2011','25-04-2011','29-04-2011','02-05-2011','30-05-2011','29-08-2011','26-12-2011','27-12-2011','01-01-2012','02-01-2012') then 0 else 1 end working_day
from dual
connect by level <= 1825 + sysdate - to_date('01-01-2000') ) 
SELECT 
a.ASM_ID,
a.ASM_START_DATE,
a.ASM_END_DATE,
sum(c.working_day)-1 AS Week_Day 
From 
O_ASSESSMENTS a 
join calendar_cte c
on c.calendar_date between a.ASM_START_DATE and a.ASM_END_DATE 
WHERE a.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('TYPE1')
and a.ASM_END_DATE >= '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY      
a.ASM_ID,
a.ASM_START_DATE,
a.ASM_END_DATE
```

Comment: What prevents you from creating a calendar table?

Comment: If you can't create a table to hold the calendar data, can you create a view in the database to mimic a calendar table, similar to the CTE in my answer?

Comment: @MarkBannister: Possibly, I did try to create something like that I think previously but it didn't create the desired results.

Comment: @TonyAndrews:  We're a managed service which means we can't create our own tables and have to request it from our DBA which isn't the easiest process in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Perhaps the simplest might be to create a CTE that produces a virtual calendar table, based on Oracle's `connect by` syntax, and then join it to the Assesments table, like so:

```
with calendar_cte as (
select to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1 calendar_date,
       case when to_char(to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1, 'Day') 
                in ('Sunday   ','Saturday ') then 0
            when to_date('01-01-2000')+level-1
                in ('03-01-2000','21-04-2000','24-04-2000','01-05-2000','29-05-2000','28-08-2000','25-12-2000','26-12-2000','01-01-2001','13-04-2001','16-04-2001','07-05-2001','28-05-2001','27-08-2001','25-12-2001','26-12-2001','01-01-2002','29-03-2002','01-04-2002','06-04-2002','03-06-2002','04-06-2002','26-08-2002','25-12-2002','26-12-2002','01-01-2003','18-04-2003','21-04-2003','05-05-2003','26-05-2003','25-08-2003','25-12-2003','26-12-2003','01-01-2004','09-04-2004','12-04-2004','03-05-2004','31-05-2004','30-08-2004','25-12-2004','26-12-2004','27-12-2004','28-12-2004','01-01-2005','03-01-2005','25-03-2005','28-03-2005','02-05-2005','30-05-2005','29-08-2005','27-12-2005','28-12-2005','02-01-2006','14-04-2006','17-04-2006','01-05-2006','29-05-2006','28-08-2006','25-12-2006','26-12-2006','02-01-2007','06-04-2007','09-04-2007','07-05-2007','28-05-2007','27-08-2007','25-12-2007','26-12-2007','01-01-2008','21-03-2008','24-03-2008','05-05-2008','26-05-2008','25-08-2008','25-12-2008','26-12-2008','01-01-2009','10-04-2009','13-04-2009','04-05-2009','25-05-2009','31-08-2009','25-12-2009','28-12-2009','01-01-2010','02-04-2010','05-04-2010','03-05-2010','31-05-2010','30-08-2010','24-12-2010','27-12-2010','28-12-2010','31-12-2010','03-01-2011','22-04-2011','25-04-2011','29-04-2011','02-05-2011','30-05-2011','29-08-2011','26-12-2011','27-12-2011') 
                then 0 
            else 1
       end working_day
from dual
connect by level <= 36525 + sysdate - to_date('01-01-2000') )
SELECT a.ASM_ID,
       a.ASM_START_DATE,
       a.ASM_END_DATE,
       sum(c.working_day) AS Week_Day
From O_ASSESSMENTS a
join calendar_cte c 
  on c.calendar_date between a.ASM_START_DATE and a.ASM_END_DATE
WHERE a.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('TYPE1') and 
      a.ASM_END_DATE >= '01/01/2012' -- and a.ASM_ID = 'A00000'
GROUP BY
      a.ASM_ID,
      a.ASM_START_DATE,
      a.ASM_END_DATE
```

This will produce a virtual table populated with dates from 01 January 2000 to 10 years after the current date, with all weekends marked as non-working days and all days specified in the second `in` clause (ie. up to 27 December 2011) also marked as non-working days.

The drawback of this method (or any method where the holiday dates are hardcoded into the query) is that each time new holiday dates are defined, every single query that uses this approach will have to have those dates added.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I've tried this out, but the 'working_day' field doesn't seem to be coming through correctly as it's working out all days between dates rather than just the working days.  Will have a fiddle around anyway, thanks once again for the assistance!

Comment: @bawpie: Which date ranges did you try this against? (Also, note that it needs to be `sum(working_day)`, **not** `count(working_day)`.)

Comment: I've run it against one record, in the query I posted, it returned 48 days between 07/11/2011 and 13/01/2012.  Running against the same record using your query (which is unchanged from what's you posted) it returns 66 days.  I think it could be to do with the case of the weekend day names (seems to be lower case in dual) but not sure on the actual holiday dates not been calculated).

Comment: @Bawpie: Arrgghh! Yes, the `Day` should have had an initial capital - I have amended it accordingly. Can you try it now?

Comment: Looks like it was the case of the weekends, looks like it is calculating the holidays as well, so will double check and report back. Thank you again, this is not something I could have hoped to work out by myself! - I see, by using 'Day' instead of 'day' that affects the output...makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a calendar table in Oracle, you might be better off exporting to Excel. Brute force always works.

[Networkdays()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx) "returns the number of whole working days between start_date and end_date. Working days exclude weekends and any dates identified in holidays."

Excluding weekends seems fairly straightforward. Every 7-day period will contain two weekend days.  You'll just need to take some care with the leftover days.

Holidays are a different story. You have to either store them or pass them as an argument.  If you could store them, you'd store them in a calendar table, and your problem would be over.  But you can't do that.

So you're looking at passing them as an argument. Off the top of my head--and I haven't had any tea yet this morning--I'd consider a common table expression or a wrapper for a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using excel to work this out, however, we're trying to roll out some reports to users where they can access them and refresh them without our intervention - working out things like timescales using the SQL would be the cherry on top.  If it can't be done, then we will continue to use excel, it's just a bit frustrating.  Theoretically we could provide the user with a template which they copy the data into to work out timescales, but it'd be nice to cut that step out completely.

Comment: @bawpie: You can [query a database from within Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/msquery1_1.htm).