# How to retrieve data for every single day in a period in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

**What I want:**

I want to have the work model for every single day in a period and for every single employee. That is, i have a table containing work models for all employees of a company. The work models are assigned for a certain period to employees. So, an employee may have more than one work model in a year. So what i want to do is to retrieve the work model for every single day in any date range and for any single employee. Is it possible in SQL? If yes, how should I proceed?

I´m working with SQl Developper version 3.0.04. The database is from Oracle.

For a better unterstanding of my problem follow the link below to have a look at the schema of the table containing the data as well as of the table which shows how the result of my query should look like.

[Link to SQLFiddle for the Schemas](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a167/4)

Table employee shows the table containing the work models assigned to employees and which period the´re valid for. The first row indicates that employee 1 has been assigned the work model 52101 from 01.01.2000 to 21.06.2009.

Table result shows how the result of my query for a date range should look like. Date range is from 19.02.2013 to 23.02.2013.

### I used the following SQL query to generate days in the date range:

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(to_date('19.02.2013'))-1+rownum,'dd/mm/yyyy') days
FROM all_objects
WHERE ROWNUM <= (to_date('23.02.2013') - to_date('19.02.2013'))+1
```

---

Notwithstanding I can´t come forward to assign for every single day and for every single employee the right work model.

thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Seeing an example of the schema would help

Comment: If you can post the relevant part of your schema that would help.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Start by *selecting* from the table with the data and add a where clause to filter the period of dates you require...

Comment: I wanted to add the schema of the table as a picture. But I couldn´t because i must have at least 10 points reputation. How could i upload the pic?

Comment: @brice diogni, please don't add pictures, use SQL Fiddle and add link to it, here is a simple example how to do it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94be8/1

Comment: @ Kordirko, thanks for the tip. I´ll build the schema and put the link here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a list of dates, better use this way:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + LEVEL
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY TO_DATE('18.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy')+LEVEL <= TO_DATE('23.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Comment: @ Wernfried, What is difference between ROWNUM and LEVEL?

Comment: In this both are working. Pseudo column LEVEL shows the level of a record in hierarchical query. Since this query does not return any hierarchy it is equal to ROWNUM. in earlier release of Oracle (till 10g) you had to use this way: `SELECT ROWNUM n
FROM (SELECT 1 just_a_column FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Wernfried and the following post: [Link to a almost similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892683/calculating-working-days-including-holidays-between-dates-without-a-calendar-tab?rq=1),I found the solution to my problem. here ist the query, which is very easy at the end of day but it was a challenge for me.

```
With calendar_cte As (
SELECT TO_DATE('19.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy')+ LEVEL-1 days
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY Level <= (TO_DATE('23.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - TO_DATE('19.02.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))+1)
Select c.days,e.employee,e.work_model,e.country,e.calendar
from employee e inner join calendar_cte c on c.days between e.valid_from and e.valid_to;
```