# Select 10th working day from my calendar table

Tags: oracle, date, select, calendar

I have a table where there are 2 columns DATE and HOLIDAY_FLAG.

```
DATE                    HOLIDAY_FLAG
01-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
02-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
03-JUL-2015 00.00.00    Y
04-JUL-2015 00.00.00    Y 
05-JUL-2015 00.00.00    Y
06-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
07-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
08-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
09-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
10-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
11-JUL-2015 00.00.00    Y
12-JUL-2015 00.00.00    Y
13-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
14-JUL-2015 00.00.00    N
```

I want to provide required date in the where condition and get the date of the next 5th working day.

```
Example:
Input  01-JUL-2015 00.00.00
Output 09-JUL-2015 00.00.00
```

Here is what i have done so far

```
select b.DATE + 5
from CALENDAR b
where b.DATE = '01-JUL-2015 00.00.00'
and b.HOLIDAY_FLAG is not null;
```

I know this doesn't work

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360812/4879022) using functions

Comment: One more [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894702/4879022)

Comment: @Varan, plz test the sql provided below and let me know if its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to use analytical function `lead()`:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f600d/1)</sup>

```
select d5 
  from (
    select cal_date, lead(cal_date, 5) over (order by cal_date) d5
      from calendar where holiday_flag='N')
  where cal_date = date '2015-07-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below SQL would do the trick. Can you try and let me know ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f600d/14/0

```
    SELECT CAL_DATE
  FROM (SELECT CA.CAL_DATE, ROWNUM AS RECNUM FROM CALENDAR CA WHERE HOLIDAY_FLAG = 'N') ABC,
       (SELECT ROWNUM AS REQRECNUM
          FROM CALENDAR
         WHERE HOLIDAY_FLAG = 'N'
           AND CAL_DATE = DATE '2015-07-01') BBC
 WHERE ABC.RECNUM = BBC.REQRECNUM + 5
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Salute to your superior knowledge. Thank You. But I have restrictions on using rownum so maybe  i'll have to find another way around.